# Get all <td> title of a table column with coded ui

Tags: c#, html, linq, coded-ui-tests

I need to check a filter function on a table.

This filter is only on the first cell of each row and I'm trying to figure out how to get all those values...

I tried with something like

```
public bool CheckSearchResults(HtmlControl GridTable, string FilterTxt)
{
    List<string> Elements = new List<string>();

    foreach (HtmlCell cell in GridTable.GetChildren())
    {
        Elements.Add(cell.FilterProperties["title"]);
    }
    List<string> Results = Elements.FindAll(l => l.Contains(FilterTxt));
    return Results.Count == Elements.Count;
}
```

but I get stuck at the foreach loop...
maybe there's a simply way with linq, but i don't know it so much

---

edit:
all the cells i need have the same custom html tag.

with this code i should get them all, but i don't know how to iterate

```
HtmlDocument Document = this.UIPageWindow.UIPageDocument;
HtmlControl GridTable = this.UIPageWindow.UIPageDocument.UIPageGridTable;
HtmlCell Cells = new HtmlCell(GridTable);
Cells.FilterProperties["custom_control"] = "firstCellOfRow";
```

also because there's no GetEnumerator function or query models for HtmlCell objects, which are part of **Microsoft.VisualStudio**.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControl library -.-

---

edit2:
i found [this article](http://executeautomation.com/blog/how-to-identify-all-the-child-elements-within-a-page-in-coded-ui-test-cuit/) and i tried this

```
public bool CheckSearchResults(string FilterTxt)
{
    HtmlDocument Document = this.UIPageWindow.UIPageDocument;
    HtmlControl GridTable = this.UIPageWindow.UIPageDocument.UIPageGridTable;

    HtmlRow rows = new HtmlRow(GridTable);
    rows.SearchProperties[HtmlRow.PropertyNames.Class] = "ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr";

    HtmlControl cells = new HtmlControl(rows);
    cells.SearchProperties["custom_control"] = "firstCellOfRow";

    UITestControlCollection collection = cells.FindMatchingControls();

    List<string> Elements = new List<string>();

    foreach (UITestControl elem in collection)
    {
        HtmlCell cell = (HtmlCell)elem;
        Elements.Add(cell.GetProperty("Title").ToString());
    }
    List<string> Results = Elements.FindAll(l => l.Contains(FilterTxt));
    return Results.Count == Elements.Count;
}
```

but i get an empty collection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved scraping pages html by myself

```
static public List<string> GetTdTitles(string htmlCode, string TdSearchPattern)
{
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(htmlCode);
    HtmlNodeCollection collection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@" + TdSearchPattern + "]");
    List<string> Results = new List<string>();
    foreach (HtmlNode node in collection)
    {
        Results.Add(node.InnerText);
    }

    return Results;
}
```

I'm freakin' hating those stupid coded ui test -.-

btw, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Try `Cell.Title` or `Cell.GetProperty("Title")`. SearchProperties and FilterProperties are only there for searching for a UI element. They either come from the UIMap or from code if you fill them out with hand. Otherwise your code should should work.

Or you can use a LINQ query (?) like:

```
var FilteredElements = 
    from Cell in UIMap...GridTable.GetChildren()
    where Cell.GetProperty("Title").ToString().Contains(FilterTxt)
    select Cell;
```

You could also try to record a cell, add it to the UIMap, set its search or filter properties to match your filtering, then call `UIMap...Cell.FindMatchingControls()` and it should return all matching cells.

---

The problem now is that you are limiting your search for one row of the table. `HtmlControl cells = new HtmlControl(rows);` here the constructor parameter sets a search limit container and not the direct parent of the control. It should be the GridTable if you want to search all cells in the table. Best solution would be to use the recorder to get a cell control then modify its search and filter properties in the UIMap to match all cells you are looking for. Tho in my opinion you should stick with a hand coded filtering. Something like:

```
foreach(var row in GridTable.GetChildren())
{
    foreach(var cell in row.GetChildren())
    {
        //filter cell here
    }
}
```

Check with AccExplorer or the recorder if the hierarchy is right. You should also use debug to be sure if the loops are getting the right controls and see the properties of the cells so you will know if the filter function is right.

Comment: nope, it doesn't work in no way :( i edited the question

Comment: Looked at the edited post. The HtmlCell, and basicly every UIControl class CUIT uses, represents ONE UI element. If you want to get all Cells that meet the crtireias you set you have to use the FindMatchingControlls function of your Cells class (as mentioned above). If it doesn't work that means you have to fiddle around with the search properties and filter properties of your control.

Comment: i tried FindMatchingControls with no luck... i edited the question again adding more details

Comment: Mmm I see what you are trying to do but it's not quite right :S. You are limiting your search for one row, that is not good if you want to get all cells in the table. And you should put all your filtering in the cell's search/filter properties so the FindMatchingControls function gets all the cells you want. Anyway edited my post with a possible solution.

Comment: i tried all your suggestions but nothing works. (The recorder is pretty useless) I wrote a function to get td titles by scraping the pages html. Stupid coded ui :D